# SQL many to many relationship - updating matches

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a many-to-many relationship between 2 entities, lets say A and B. I'm try to find a good way to batch-replace rows in the junction-table (remove all appearances of ids from B that matches a certain id from A, and add new rows instead). The simplest solution is to split it to 2 operations - delete all rows that refers to some entity in table A, and afterwards add new rows to refer to the relevant entities in table B.
It sounds a bit complicated (2 separate operations that needs to be executed one after the other and not in parallel) for the goal I'm trying to achieve, so I wondered if there is a better idea to solve this issue.

Comment: I’m not sure why you think this sounds a bit complicated - it seems to be pretty straightforward and I’m not sure how any other solution could be significantly simpler

Comment: Have you identified a real reason to optimize? If so: The question title suggests an update, while the goal you describe involves "remove" and "add". Do you have a case for not updating existing rows?